# "Сегодня и ближайшую неделю"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Получил такое сообщение недавно:

> ...Сегодня и ближайшую неделю за покупки по карте вы получите...

Я прав был, когда мне показалось, что не хватает предлога: "**в** ближайшую неделю"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да конечно, предлог пропущен, тут и говорить не о чем.

Другой вопрос, как это веяние охарактеризовать. То ли какой-то анахронизм (в украинском, например, сохранилось схожее "цього тіжня" как единственно возможное, это правда, родительный падеж). То ли наоборот - новояз какой-то под действием английского.

Скажу честно: неправильно, но вот ощущения какой-то совсем уж нетерпимой дикости не вызывает. Ну почему можно "прошлым летом", но обязательно надо "на прошлой неделе"? Вот что-то на этом уровне у меня срабатывает, что препятствует отношению к подобным конструкциям как к грубо неправильным. Субъективно, разумеется.

Comment: Да, я тоже подумал, что это может быть и влияние английского (this week) и просто упрощенчество у менее грамотных.

Answer (score 1):

Если какими-то действиями охватывается весь временной интервал (подразумевается *вся неделя*, смысл "на протяжении ближайшей недели"), то предлог не нужен:

> Сегодня и [всю] ближайшую неделю горячая вода подаваться не будет.

Обратный случай (событие внутри интервала, и предлог необходим):

> **В** ближайшую неделю будет произведено отключение горячей воды.

Книжный пример (Борис Пильняк, К. Б. Андроникашвили-Пильняк, Терра-Книжный клуб, 2003)

> *...не согласился один только наш режиссер А. В. Нагорный-Латрыгин —*
>   *старик больно комический — ссылаясь на то, что он **следующую неделю***
>   ***будет занят*** в Дворянском клубе:

Аналогично, если льгота на покупки по карте действует в течение всей недели:

> Сегодня и (всю) **ближайшую неделю** за покупки по карте вы **будете**
>   получ**ать** удвоенное количество баллов.

Но в *исходном примере* временной интервал (неделя) и действие (оно выражено глаголом *совершенного вида*) *рассогласованы* по продолжительности: создаётся впечатление (возможно, вопреки желаемому смыслу), что у покупателей на упомянутой неделе появится возможность что-то получить один раз. Но при таком смысле событие находится внутри интервала ("**в**" нём), поэтому вариант без предлога **не** годится.

Comment: Да, непонятно они выразились. Но вообще мне это сообщение до феньки. ;) Какие-то бонусы "спасибо" предлагают.

Comment: Не отвергая сути сказанного, выскажу предположение, что дело не в совершенном виде глагола, а в том, что "следующую неделю"  и "ближайшую неделю" требуют разного управления. **Сегодня и следующую неделю** субъективно вызывает гораздо меньше неприятия, а то и вовсе находится на грани разговорной нормативности.